# i get a empty table in foreach inside foreach : php

Tags: php, mysql

When in a form a user adds a number of schools, for example 3,
another form will appear which contains 3 lines containing the information of these 3 schools, and at the end I add the contents of the two forms in two tables.

In the first, `wp_mairie_details`, I add the information of the user.
In the second table I add the information of the schools.

I want to display the user's lists with the schools that last added in the form.
My first loop is displayed correctly but the second one displays the correct number of schools but I get an empty table.

```
        <?php               
            foreach ( $dump_ecoles_classes_1 as $i => $ecoles_classe ) {
        ?>
        <div class="abonn_style">
            <span class="span_abonn_style">Nomde la mairie :</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="nom_mairie" value="<?php echo  $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['nom_mairie']; ?>" disabled class="span_abonn_style"> 
            <br>
            <span class="span_abonn_style">Adresse:</span><br>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="adress"  value="<?php echo   $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['adress']; ?>" disabled class="span_abonn_style">
                </textarea>
            <br> 
            <span class="span_abonn_style">Responsable du projet:</span><br>
            <input type="text" class="span_abonn_style" name="responsable" value="<?php echo    $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['responsable']; ?>" disabled>

            <br>
            <span class="span_abonn_style">E-mail:</span><br>
            <input type="email" class="span_abonn_style" name="email" value="<?php echo $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['email']; ?>" disabled>   
            <br>
            <span class="span_abonn_style">Nombre de ecoles:</span><br>
            <input type="number" name="ecoles" class="span_abonn_style" value="<?php echo   $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['ecoles']; ?>" disabled >

            <br>


            <?php 

            $i_var = $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['ecoles'];

            $mairie_ecoles_row = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT me.nom_ecole_mairie,me.responsable_mairie,me.email_mairie,me.nbr_classes_mairie,me.nbr_eleves_mairie,me.id_user FROM wp_mairie_ecoles me 
            INNER JOIN wp_mairie_details md ON md.id_user = me.id_user 
            INNER JOIN wp_pmpro_membership_orders mo ON mo.user_id = md.id_user 
            where me.id_user = '".$dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['id_user']."'
            order by md.id_user");


            $row_mairie_ecoles = objectToArray($mairie_ecoles_row);



            foreach ( $row_mairie_ecoles as $k => $row_mairie_ecole ) {
            ?>
            <table class="trios_table">
            <tr class="trios_tr_style">
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">Nom de l’école
                </th>                                       
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">responsable
                </th>                                     
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">email
                </th>                                       
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">Nbre/classes
                </th> 
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">Nbre/élèves
                </th> 
            </tr>

            <tr class="trios_tr_style">
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php   
                echo    $row_mairie_ecoles[$k]['nom_ecole_mairie'];

                ?>
                </td>
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php 
                    echo    $row_mairie_ecoles[$k]['responsable_mairie'];

                ?>
                </td>
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php 
                    echo    $row_mairie_ecoles[$k]['email_mairie'];
                ?>
                </td>
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php 
                    echo    $row_mairie_ecoles[$k]['nbr_classes_mairie'];
                ?>
                </td>
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php 
                    echo    $row_mairie_ecolesrow_mairie_ecoles[$k]['nbr_eleves_mairie'];
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <?php   // } ?>

        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please realize we do not have all the data to debug that.  See [mcve].  Ensure that each step produces the expected result.  Ex. `$dump_ecoles_classes_1`, `$row_marie_ecoles` and many others have the result you expect.  Does your query return what you expect?    One detail, in your second `foreach` you echo on `$row_mairie_ecoles`.  Should it not be on `$row_mairie_ecole` which is the value you set in the `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php               
            foreach ( $dump_ecoles_classes_1 as $i => $ecoles_classe ) {
        ?>
        <div class="abonn_style">
            <span class="span_abonn_style">Nomde la mairie :</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="nom_mairie" value="<?php echo  $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['nom_mairie']; ?>" disabled class="span_abonn_style"> 
            <br>
            <span class="span_abonn_style">Adresse:</span><br>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="adress"  value="<?php echo   $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['adress']; ?>" disabled class="span_abonn_style">
                </textarea>
            <br> 
            <span class="span_abonn_style">Responsable du projet:</span><br>
            <input type="text" class="span_abonn_style" name="responsable" value="<?php echo    $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['responsable']; ?>" disabled>

            <br>
            <span class="span_abonn_style">E-mail:</span><br>
            <input type="email" class="span_abonn_style" name="email" value="<?php echo $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['email']; ?>" disabled>   
            <br>
            <span class="span_abonn_style">Nombre de ecoles:</span><br>
            <input type="number" name="ecoles" class="span_abonn_style" value="<?php echo   $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['ecoles']; ?>" disabled >

            <br>


            <?php 

            $i_var = $dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['ecoles'];

            $mairie_ecoles_row = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT me.nom_ecole_mairie,me.responsable_mairie,me.email_mairie,me.nbr_classes_mairie,me.nbr_eleves_mairie,me.id_user FROM wp_mairie_ecoles me 
            INNER JOIN wp_mairie_details md ON md.id_user = me.id_user 
            INNER JOIN wp_pmpro_membership_orders mo ON mo.user_id = md.id_user 
            where me.id_user = '".$dump_ecoles_classes_1[$i]['id_user']."'
            order by md.id_user");


            $row_mairie_ecoles = objectToArray($mairie_ecoles_row);

            foreach ( $row_mairie_ecoles as $k => $row_mairie_ecole ) {
            ?>
            <table class="trios_table">
            <tr class="trios_tr_style">
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">Nom de l’école
                </th>                                       
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">responsable
                </th>                                     
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">email
                </th>                                       
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">Nbre/classes
                </th> 
                <th style="border: 2px solid black!important;background: #e4e4e4;">Nbre/élèves
                </th> 
            </tr>

            <tr class="trios_tr_style">
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php   
                echo    $row_mairie_ecoles[$k]['nom_ecole_mairie'];
                ?>
                </td>
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php 
                    echo    $row_mairie_ecoles[$k]['responsable_mairie'];

                ?>
                </td>
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php 
                    echo    $row_mairie_ecoles[$k]['email_mairie'];
                ?>
                </td>
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php 
                    echo    $row_mairie_ecoles[$k]['nbr_classes_mairie'];
                ?>
                </td>
                <td class="trios_td_style trios_td_style_1 ">
                <?php 
                    echo    $row_mairie_ecolesrow_mairie_ecoles[$k]['nbr_eleves_mairie'];
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <?php    } ?>

        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```